# Error while trying to run JAR of project having Hibernate from command prompt

Tags: java, hibernate

I am novice in Hibernate technology.
I have a Java project which uses Hibernate.
When I run the project from Netbeans IDE the project runs fine without any issues.

However when I run the JAR file of the project from command prompt I get an exception

> "org.hibernate.hql.ast.QuerySyntaxException:"
>   XXXX is not mapped.

I have included all the Jars required for the execution of this project.Also I have imported `javax.persistence.Entity`.

Appreciate if you can help me out in this issue.

-Adish

Comment: You don't need hbm.xml if you are using annotations, annotations are an equivalent to Hibernate mapping files.

Answer (score 0):

You have to have .hbm.xml mapping objects to tables somewhere so Hibernate can read them.  It's an ORM tool - JARs aren't sufficient.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely, the mapping files are not included into the generated .jar. Check their presence.

Put the mapping files in a folder included in the class path of the application. I don't use Netbeans, the feature might be called *exported entries* or *build class path* in the project settings.

Mapping files can be recognized easily, they end with the `hbm.xml` extension.

Comment: Thanks Samuel_xL and duffymo for your quick response.
I am using hibernate annotations in my code.
As mentioned I was not able to find any file with hbm.xml extension in the created JAR. 
So as per suggestion I will have hbm.xml mappings.
Thank you for quick response.

Answer (score 0):

> However when I run the Jar file of the project from command prompt I get an exception "org.hibernate.hql.ast.QuerySyntaxException:" XXXX is not mapped.

The message is self explaining, you have somewhere a query that references a class that is considered as a non mapped class. Double check that:

- XXXX is on the classpath.
- XXXX is properly annotated.
- XXXX is listed in the `EntityManager` configuration (or `AnnotationConfiguration`, what you're using is unclear).